# Does developing a PHP site that listens and responds in JSON is equivalent to developing an API?

Tags: php, json, api

I am writing project Abstract Plan for this web platform I developed but I am confused with API and what should I name my Phases.

I developed this in 3 phases:

1. First I created a tables and defined relationship between them and
   then I build a PHP Application that posts and gets data from
   database.
2. Then, I developed a PHP application that need JSON as POST and
       replies in JSON using the above developed application. DO I CALL
       THIS API?
3. And finally, now I can use this application with any other
   application, I have already implemented with Android and now I am
   implementing in Python for GUI on Windows. Basically, now anyone can
   use the above developed PHP program to create their custom app by
   sending correct JSON encoded data.

Is my PHP program an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An API is an Application Program Interface a.k.a. a way for other programs to interact with yours. What you've described is a RESTful API, so yeah it would be considered one.

Comment: Okay. And is it necessary for my API to send HTTP STATUS CODES with response?

Comment: No they will happen automatically. But you shoudl be sure all the calls that actually get to this API return sensible error status, rather than just nothing if something does go wrong in your API code

Comment: How can I make sure that? For example, currently if users send wrong password I send message in response (just like I send when its success) and with success code -1!

Comment: It's up to you if you wanna change the request Status code, or if you simply want to add an error code to the response. I personally would go with the latter.

Comment: Okay.. I will google how to add Error Code.

So basically, if I add error code, my Application in Android will not take the reply as response rather it will parse it in ERROR section. And it will save me a hell lot of code lines in which I check the error